# Can we prove that any set of finite strings without substrings is finite?

Tags: formal-languages, strings, finite-sets

I want to prove (or disprove) the following conjecture:

> Let $\Sigma$ be a finite alphabet, and let $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$
> satisfy that there are no $v, w \in L$ such that $v$ is a proper
> substring of $w$. Then $L$ is finite.

I have the intuition that this is true, haven't been able to find a counter example, but am unable to prove it. If this is true, how can we prove it? If this is false, how can we construct such infinite $L$?

Comment: Note that you wrote $L \in \Sigma ^*$ in the question, but it should be $L \subseteq \Sigma ^*$. Set $\Sigma^*$ is a set of words, not a set of languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that by *substring* you mean *consecutive substring*, take
$$ L= \{10^n1 : n \ge 0\}. $$

On the other hand, if you refer to nonconsecutive substrings, or *subsequence* ordering, then [Higman's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%27s_lemma) states that any set of incomparable strings is indeed finite.